# Flatten a column value using dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Im trying to flatten 2 columns from a table loaded into a dataframe as below:

| u_group | t_group |
| --- | --- |
| {"link": "https://hi.com/api/now/table/system/2696f18b376bca0", "value": "2696f18b376bca0"} | {"link": "https://hi.com/api/now/table/system/2696f18b376bca0", "value": "2696f18b376bca0"} |
| {"link": "https://hi.com/api/now/table/system/99b27bc1db761f4", "value": "99b27bc1db761f4"} | {"link": "https://hi.com/api/now/table/system/99b27bc1db761f4", "value": "99b27bc1db761f4"} |

I want to separate them and get them as:

| u_group.link | u_group.value | t_group.link | t_group.value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| https://hi.com/api/now/table/system/2696f18b376bca0 | 2696f18b376bca0 | https://hi.com/api/now/table/system/2696f18b376bca0 | 2696f18b376bca0 |
| https://hi.com/api/now/table/system/99b27bc1db761f4 | 99b27bc1db761f4 | https://hi.com/api/now/table/system/99b27bc1db761f4 | 99b27bc1db761f4 |

I used the below code, but wasnt successful.

```
import ast
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df12 = spark.sql("""select u_group,t_group from tbl""")

def only_dict(d):
    '''
    Convert json string representation of dictionary to a python dict
    '''
    return ast.literal_eval(d)

def list_of_dicts(ld):
    '''
    Create a mapping of the tuples formed after 
    converting json strings of list to a python list   
    '''
    return dict([(list(d.values())[1], list(d.values())[0]) for d in ast.literal_eval(ld)])

A = json_normalize(df12['u_group'].apply(only_dict).tolist()).add_prefix('link.')
B = json_normalize(df['u_group'].apply(list_of_dicts).tolist()).add_prefix('value.')
```

TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Kindly help or suggest if any other code would work better.

Answer (score 0):

need simple example and code for answer

example:

```
data = [[{'link':'A1', 'value':'B1'}, {'link':'A2', 'value':'B2'}], 
        [{'link':'C1', 'value':'D1'}, {'link':'C2', 'value':'D2'}]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['u', 't'])
```

output(`df`):

```
    u                               t
0   {'link': 'A1', 'value': 'B1'}   {'link': 'A2', 'value': 'B2'}
1   {'link': 'C1', 'value': 'D1'}   {'link': 'C2', 'value': 'D2'}
```

use following code:

```
pd.concat([df[i].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x)).add_prefix(i + '_') for i in df.columns], axis=1)
```

output:

```
    u_link  u_value t_link  t_value
0   A1      B1      A2      B2
1   C1      D1      C2      D2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my 2 cents,

A simple way to achieve this using PYSPARK.

1. Create the dataframe as follows:

   ```
   data = [
       (
           """{"link": "https://hi.com/api/now/table/system/2696f18b376bca0", "value": "2696f18b376bca0"}""",
           """{"link": "https://hi.com/api/now/table/system/2696f18b376bca0", "value": "2696f18b376bca0"}"""
       ),
       (
           """{"link": "https://hi.com/api/now/table/system/2696f18b376bca0", "value": "2696f18b376bca0"}""",
           """{"link": "https://hi.com/api/now/table/system/99b27bc1db761f4", "value": "99b27bc1db761f4"}"""
       )
   ]
   df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema=['u_group','t_group'])
   ```
2. Then use the from_json() to parse the dictionary and fetch the individual values as follows:

   ```
   from pyspark.sql.types import *
   from pyspark.sql.functions import *


   schema_column = StructType([
       StructField("link",StringType(),True), 
       StructField("value",StringType(),True), 
   ])


   df = df .withColumn('U_GROUP_PARSE',from_json(col('u_group'),schema_column))\
           .withColumn('T_GROUP_PARSE',from_json(col('t_group'),schema_column))\
           .withColumn('U_GROUP.LINK',col("U_GROUP_PARSE.link"))\
           .withColumn('U_GROUP.VALUE',col("U_GROUP_PARSE.value"))\
           .withColumn('T_GROUP.LINK',col("T_GROUP_PARSE.link"))\
           .withColumn('T_GROUP.VALUE',col("T_GROUP_PARSE.value"))\
           .drop('u_group','t_group','U_GROUP_PARSE','T_GROUP_PARSE')
   ```
3. Print the dataframe

   ```
    df.show(truncate=False)
   ```

Please check the below image for your reference:

[image]